# How to stub a Rails helper/module method in Rspec 3 feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

I've seen this done using the older `should_receive` syntax, but I can't figure out how to stub a Rails module method in Rspec 3.

I've tried these:

```
OptionsHelper.stubs(:method).returns("something")
allow(OptionsHelper).to receive(:method).and_return "something"
allow_any_instance_of(ActionView::Base).to receive(:render_quick_help).and_return 'something'
```

But none actually stub the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
allow_any_instance_of(ActionView::Base)
```

Means it will expect instance of that exact class and not classes that inherit from it to receive :method.

Also ActionView::Base is a class, ActionView:: is a module.

Furthermore, Modules can not be instantiated, so in theory allow_any_instance_of(ActionView).to ... will have no effect.

I know it's not a solution, but should point you in right direction.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I'm in the "grasping at straws" stage now.

Comment: Are you calling: 

  render "my/view"

in you test? I'm assuming it's a View spec? Could you post full source?

Comment: Possibly, you could check if some element of quick help was rendered. ex:

    .
    expect(rendered).to match /This is only present in quick help/

Comment: It's a feature spec.  Please see the question title.

Comment: Test to see if 'view' method is available within your 'scenario', if not you'll have to use [View Spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec)